# Most efficient way to find spaces within a square on a 2D Cartesian grid?

Tags: geometry

The context here is that I'm writing a method to randomly place items on a game map and I want to be able to define an area around the items that is empty so they each have some breathing room. I'd still like to find a more efficient method if anyone has any ideas. I implemented this solution but it is slower than I'd like.

What's the most efficient way to find all spaces within a square with a given length centered on a given space in a 2D Cartesian grid? I get in over my head rapidly with math jargon so searching didn't help much.

Say I have a regular 2D grid, like graph paper. Pick a coordinate $c$ and make it the center of a square extending d distance from that point. So the square extends from $c-d$ to $c+d$ in both dimensions. Is there a clever/efficient way to get all the graph spaces falling within this square or am I overthinking it?

[image]

I mean get a list of all grid spaces in the square.

Comment: Please elaborate more on what you mean. In the current form, it's not possible to understand what you are asking form.

Comment: Could you maybe provide an image to clarify what you mean with graph spaces? And what is meant by "getting them"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the coordinates of the centerpoint are $(c_1, c_2)$, then the coordinates of the cells are all given by $(c_1 + l, c_2 + k)$, where both $l$ and $k$ range from $-d$ to $d$.

An algorithm that outputs all coordinates would work like this:

- Choose $l = -d$ and print $(c_1 - d, c_2 - d), (c_1 - d, c_2 - d + 1), \ldots, (c_1 - d, c_2 + d)$
- Choose $l = -d + 1$ and print $(c_1 - d - 1, c_2 - d), (c_1 - d - 1, c_2 - d + 1), \ldots, (c_1 - d - 1, c_2 + d)$.
- $\ldots$
- Choose $l = d$ and print $(c_1 + d, c_2 - d), (c_1 + d, c_2 - d + 1), \ldots, (c_1 + d, c_2 + d)$.

Comment: So pretty straight forward then, thanks!